# Can we have a magic link to the homework policy?

Tags: feature-request, comments, links, markdown

I just stumbled on [this fantastic list of magic shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/184688):

> Supported magic links:
>
> - `[meta]` – link to the current site's Meta; link text is the site name (e.g. "Super User Meta"). Does nothing if the site doesn't have (or already is) a Meta site.
> - `[main]` – like [meta], just the other way around.
> - `[edit]` – link to the edit page for the post the comment is on, i.e. /posts/{id}/edit. Link text is "edit" (capitalization is respected).
>
> [ ... ]
>
> - `[ask]`, `[answer]` – link to the "How to Ask" / "How to Answer" page.
> - `[something.se]` – link to something.stackexchange.com, if that site exists. Link text is the site name. Use `[ubuntu.se]` for Ask Ubuntu.
>
> Except for `[chat]` and `[edit]`, and with the addition of `[chat-faq]`, these also work in chat.

and they do, in fact, render correctly (see comments below). This makes me think of one particular link I keep giving to people: the homework policy.

## **Can we have [homework-policy] magicize to [Homework Policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/)?**

Comment: On `[main]`, you are expected to write proper English (as advertised on `[english.se]`), but here on `[metase]` it's more important to have freehand circles, so please `[edit]` your post, otherwise I'll have to flag you (see the `[FAQ#flagging]`). If you're unsure how to use your keyboard, `[su]` is the right place to ask. There's no Q&A site about unicorns yet, but you can suggest one on `[area51.se]`.

Comment: On [main], you are expected to write proper English (as advertised on [english.se]), but here on [metase] it's more important to have freehand circles, so please [edit] your post, otherwise I'll have to flag you (see the [FAQ#flagging]). If you're unsure how to use your keyboard, [su] is the right place to ask. There's no Q&A site about unicorns yet, but you can suggest one on [area51.se].

Comment: Try to remember "questions/714".

Comment: I do. But this is better.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from David's answer, I  use [this script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) for linking to the policy. I've saved a comment with the following text:

```
Please see [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/7433). We expect homework and homework-like problems to have some effort put into them, and deal with conceptual issues. If you edit your question to explain (1) What you have tried, (2) the concept you have trouble with, and (3) your level of understanding, I'll be happy to reopen this. (Flag this message for ♦ attention with a custom message, or reply to me in the comments with `@Manishearth` to notify me)
```

While the close reason covers much of this now (indeed, one of the reasons for the close reason was to  incorporate the boilerplate comments into the system, enabling users to focus on the *exact* problem in the question), I still use this for getting the link to the policy.

Answer (score 1):

Magic links are only implemented for standard URLs that are present on every site, so unless we hear otherwise from the developers, I would not expect this to happen.